# Create a DateTimeFormater with an Optional Section at Beginning

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time

I have timecodes with this structure `hh:mm:ss.SSS` for which i have a  own Class, implementing the Temporal Interface.
It has the custom Field TimecodeHour Field allowing values greater than 23 for hour.
I want to parse with DateTimeFormatter. The hour value is optional (can be omitted, and hours can be greater than 24); as RegEx `(\d*\d\d:)?\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d`

For the purpose of this Question my custom Field can be replaced with the normal HOUR_OF_DAY Field.

My current Formatter

```
DateTimeFormatter UNLIMITED_HOURS = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2, 2,SignStyle.NEVER)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .parseDefaulting(TimecodeHour.HOUR, 0)
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter TIMECODE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendOptional(UNLIMITED_HOURS)
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .appendFraction(MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3, 3, true)
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Timecodes with a hour value parse as expected, but values with hours omittet throw an Exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20:33.123' could not be parsed at index 5
```

I assume, as hour and minute have the same pattern, the parser starts at front and captures the minute value for the optional section.
Is this right, and how can solve this?

Comment: What is `TimecodeHour.HOUR`? Doesn't seem to be part of the JDK

Comment: @Michael TimecodeHour is my own class; a custom Field allowing values for HOUR greater than 23.

Comment: Please include it in the question, in order that people can copy your code into their IDE and run it.

Comment: Does a `TimecodeHour` represent an amount of time, e.g., a duration, rather than a time of day? If so, don’t use any `Temporal` for it. If you want to make your own class, it may implement `TemporalAmount`. You may also be happy with just using the `Duration` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with two optional parts (one with hours, other without) like in:

```
var formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .optionalStart()
      .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2, 4, SignStyle.NEVER).appendLiteral(":")
      .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2).appendLiteral(":")
      .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .optionalEnd()
    .optionalStart()
      .parseDefaulting(HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
      .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2).appendLiteral(":")
      .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

<sub>I do not know about `TimecodeHour`, so I used `HOUR_OF_DAY` to test</sub>
<sup>(also too lazy to include fractions)</sup>

Comment: Don't think this will work. If both parts are optional, this will accept an empty string, right? Or a string containing both parts like 11:22:33.4411:22.33. You'd need some way to do a kind of logical OR, and there is none

Comment: @user15793316 Wonderful your approach seems to work, i will later see if it passes all the tests

Comment: @Michael i testet his aproach: empty strings throw an exception, a String containing both variants concatenated together works returning the values from the first one.

Answer (score 4):

I started to suspect that `20:33.123` wasn’t meant to indicate a time of day between 20 and 21 minutes past midnight. Maybe rather an amount of time, a little longer than 20 minutes. If this is correct, use a `Duration` for it.

Unfortunately java.time does not include means for parsing and formatting a `Duration` in other than ISO 8601 format. This leaves us with at least three options:

1. Use a third-party library. Time4J offers an elegant solution, see below. Joda-Time has its `PeriodFormatter` class. Apache may also offer facilities for parsing and formatting of durations.
2. Convert your string to ISO 8601 format before parsing with `Duration.parse()`.
3. Write your own parser.

I was thinking that we’re too lazy for 3. and that Joda-Time is getting dated, so I want to pursue options 1. and 2. here, option 1. in the Time4J variant.

### A regex for adapting to ISO 8601

ISO 8601 format for a duration feels unusual at first, but is straightforward. `PT20M33.123S` means 20 minutes 33.123 seconds.

```
public static Duration parse(String timeCodeString) {
    String iso8601 = timeCodeString
            .replaceFirst("^(\\d{2,}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}\\.\\d{3})$", "PT$1H$2M$3S")
            .replaceFirst("^(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}\\.\\d{3})$", "PT$1M$2S");
    return Duration.parse(iso8601);
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    System.out.println(parse("20:33.123"));
    System.out.println(parse("123:20:33.123"));
```

Output is:

> ```
> PT20M33.123S
> PT123H20M33.123S
> ```

My two calls to `replaceFirst` first handle the case with hours, then the case without hours. So either will convert a string that matches your regex to ISO 8601 format. Which the `Duration` class then parses. And as you can see, `Duration` also prints ISO 8601 format back. Formatting it differently is not bad, though, search for how.

### Time4J

The Time4J library offers the really elegant solution very much along the same line of thought as yours. All we really need is this formatter:

```
private static final Formatter<ClockUnit> TIME_CODE_PARSER 
        = Duration.formatter(ClockUnit.class, "[###hh:mm:ss.fff][mm:ss.fff]");
```

Simply use like this:

```
    System.out.println(TIME_CODE_PARSER.parse("20:33.123"));
    System.out.println(TIME_CODE_PARSER.parse("123:20:33.123"));
```

> ```
> PT20M33,123000000S
> PT123H20M33,123000000S
> ```

The Time4J `Duration` class too prints ISO 8601 format. It appears that it uses comma as decimal separator as is preferred in ISO 8601, and that it prints 9 decimals on the seconds also when some of them are 0.

In the format pattern string `###hh` means 2 to 5 digit hours, and `fff` means three digits of decimal fraction of second.

### Anything wrong with your approach?

Was there anything wrong with your approach? `ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY` means that: hour of day. 0 is midnight, 12 is noon and 23 is near the end of the day. This is not what you want, so yes, you are using the wrong means. While you can probably get it to work, anyone maintaining your code after you will find it confusing and will probably have a hard time making modification in line with your intentions.

### Links

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Joda-Time `PeriodFormatter`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html)
- [Time4J `TimeSpanFormatter`](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/TimeSpanFormatter.html)

Comment: Well-researched and well-explained answer! Thanks for adding `Time4J` solution as well. Also, for the same reason which you have mentioned in the section,  **Anything wrong with your approach?**, I would go with your approach.

Comment: Thank you four detailed answer. I use my code to work with Media Ressources Audio, Subtitles, etc. My Class can be really seen as a Timecode used in Videoproduction; it can be interpreted as the Duration from the beginning or a point on the media timeline.

I take a look at Time4J, seems interesting, but i think i will work with my original approach (custom Temporal with a HOURS Field instead of HOURS_PER_DAY, that Hours can be greater then 24.)
The solving answer from @user15793316  works (with a little additional check in the parsing function)

Answer (score 1):

I think fundamentally the problem is that it gets stuck going down the wrong path. It sees a field of length 2, which we know is the minutes but it believes is the hours. Once it believes the optional section is present, when we know it's not, the whole thing is destined to fail.

This is provable by changing the minimum hour length to 3.

```
.appendValue(TimecodeHour.HOUR, 3, 4, SignStyle.NEVER)
```

It now knows that the "20" cannot be hours, since hours requires at least 3 digits. With this small change, it now parses correctly, whether the optional section is present or not.

So presuming that the hours field really does need to be between 2 and 4 digits, I think you're stuck with having to implement a workaround. For example, count the number of colons in the string and use a different formatter depending on which one you run into. Using a different delimiter besides a colon for the hours would also work.

The parser logic has undergone quite a few bug fixes over the various Java versions since it was introduced - as you can imagine, there are so many potential edge cases - so I was hopeful using a recent version of Java would make this problem disappear. Unfortunately, it seems even in Java 16, the behaviour is still the same.

Comment: @user15793316 Good catch. Tested it and you're right, it does.